# Composer class not Found Error

Tags: php, composer-php, package

I've been working on a project and for which I needed to make a package. But it always returns

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'youtubetomp3\downloader' not found
```

Here the structure of directory.

```
youtubetomp3/
  src/
    downloader.php
  test/
    downloaderTest.php
  composer.json
  composer.lock
  and other files
```

The composer.json contains following details.

```
{
    "name": "princeyadav05/youtubetomp3",
    "description": "Downloads mp3 of a video given video-id",
    "keywords": ["youtube", "songs", "downloader", "package"],
    "license": "",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Prince Yadav",
            "email": "princeyadav96@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "type": "package",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4",
        "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.11.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "5.2.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "princeyadav05\\youtubetomp3\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I'm creating object of class.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'scrapper.php';
include 'database.php';

echo "** WELCOME TO THE MP3 DOWNLOADER ** \n \n";
$name = readline("Hey There. Lets start with your name : ");
echo "\nHello " . $name . ".\n";


$search = readline("Please enter the search query : ");
$data_array = searchVideo($search); //returns data array
displayVideos($data_array); // returns video id
$download = new downloader();
$video_details = $download->downloadSong($video_id);
// returns array with video title, Duration, url, path
savingToDb($video_title, $video_duration, $video_url, $songs_path);
?>
```

Please help. I've tried many things but nothing worked.I'm really frustrated.

Comment: Are you importing the package?

Comment: Can you share the code containing `$download = new downloader();`?

Comment: <?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require 'scrapper.php';
include 'database.php';
echo "** WELCOME TO THE MP3 DOWNLOADER ** \n \n";
$search = readline("Please enter the search query : ");
$data_array = searchVideo($search); //returns data array
displayVideos($data_array); // returns video id
$download = new downloader();
$video_details = $download->downloadSong($video_id);
// returns array with video title, Duration, url, path
savingToDb($video_title, $video_duration, $video_url, $songs_path);
?>

Comment: @Daan i've tried importing but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear whether you're including autoload.php file generated by composer. Would you mind posting the full code?

Then I'm not sure about your autoload directive, I would try something like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "src/"
    ]
},
```

see composer docs for more info